# An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined See "C:\Users\XXX588\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-uEZQDG\angular-errors.log"

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, angular11

I encountered the below error while serving the angular11 app to start. Please let me know how can I get rid of this error. Please find the package JSON and error log attached.

```
"devDependencies": {
            "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1102.4",
            "@angular/cli": "^11.2.2",
            "@angular/common": "^11.2.14",
            "@angular/compiler": "^11.2.14",
            "@angular/compiler-cli": "^11.2.14",
            "@angular/core": "^11.2.14",
            "@angular/forms": "^11.2.14",
            "@angular/platform-browser": "^11.2.14",
            "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^11.2.14",
            "@angular/router": "^11.2.14",
            "@babel/runtime": "^7.13.10",
            "@babel/runtime-corejs3": "^7.17.2",
            "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
            "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",
            "@types/glob": "^7.2.0",
            "@types/jasmine": "^3.10.3",
            "@types/node": "^14.14.22",
            "@types/systemjs": "^6.1.1",
            "@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs": "^2.5.0",
            "core-js": "^3.21.1",
            "glob": "^7.2.0",
            "jasmine-core": "^4.0.1",
            "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^7.0.0",
            "karma": "^6.3.17",
            "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
            "karma-coverage": "^2.2.0",
            "karma-jasmine": "^4.0.1",
            "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.7.0",
            "karma-junit-reporter": "^2.0.1",
            "karma-sonarqube-unit-reporter": "~0.0.23",
            "ng-packagr": "^11.2.0",
            "node-fetch": "2.6.1",
            "node-localstorage": "^2.1.6",
            "puppeteer": "^13.5.0",
            "rxjs": "^6.6.0",
            "ts-node": "^10.7.0",
            "tslib": "^2.3.1",
            "typescript": "~4.1.5",
            "webpack": "^5.70.0",
            "zone.js": "~0.11.5"
    }
```

Error log:

[error] TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
at C:\Projects\demo\saffbreadcrumb\node_modules@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\plugin.js:170:86
at Array.forEach ()
at C:\Projects\demo\saffbreadcrumb\node_modules@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\plugin.js:170:33
at SyncHook.eval [as call] (eval at create (C:\Projects\demo\saffbreadcrumb\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:19:10), :11:1)
at SyncHook.lazyCompileHook (C:\Projects\demo\saffbreadcrumb\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
at Compiler.newCompilation (C:\Projects\demo\saffbreadcrumb\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:630:30)
at C:\Projects\demo\saffbreadcrumb\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:667:29
at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Projects\demo\saffbreadcrumb\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), :6:1)
at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (C:\Projects\demo\saffbreadcrumb\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
at Compiler.compile (C:\Projects\demo\saffbreadcrumb\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:662:28)
at C:\Projects\demo\saffbreadcrumb\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\webpack\lib\Watching.js:77:18
at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Projects\demo\saffbreadcrumb\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), :24:1)
at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (C:\Projects\demo\saffbreadcrumb\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
at Watching._go (C:\Projects\demo\saffbreadcrumb\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\webpack\lib\Watching.js:41:32)
at C:\Projects\demo\saffbreadcrumb\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\webpack\lib\Watching.js:33:9
at Compiler.readRecords (C:\Projects\demo\saffbreadcrumb\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:529:11)